# adjust the first image view height according to second imageview

Tags: android, imageview

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight=".40"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/First"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="160px"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:padding="5dp" />

        <ImageView

            android:id="@+id/Second"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/play_small" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

I want to set the height of first imageview with id --> First according to the second image view  id -- > Second.   I am setting the second image view src from xml and i am downloading the first image from some weblink.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LayoutParams` for this task.
Firstly you have to find your second `ImageView` height, and set it to the `LayoutParams` of your first `ImageView`.

```
LayoutParams params = firstImage.getLayoutParams();
params.height = secondImage.getWidth();
firstImage.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I have tried to get the height of second image view using these two methods
imageView.getLayoutParams().height and imageView.getHeight();
First one is returning -2 and the other one is returning zero

Comment: try to set your first imageview height only after download and setting the second one.

Comment: Problem solved.
I have done it like this.
imgSecond.getDrawable().getMinimumHeight();

and adjusting the first one like 
LayoutParams params = firstImage.getLayoutParams();
params.setHeight = imgSecond.getDrawable().getMinimumHeight() ;
firstImage.setLayoutParams(params);

Comment: If this answer helps you, then please accept the same. ;)